# Plotting two graphics in the same Figure in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to plot two different graphics in the same figure in Tkinter (the thing is that I would like them to share their toolbar). The closest I got is this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg,
    NavigationToolbar2Tk
)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create a figure
        figure = Figure() # (figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)

        # create FigureCanvasTkAgg object
        figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure)

        # create the toolbar
        NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure_canvas, self)

        # create axes
        axes1 = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        axes2 = figure.add_subplot(2,1,2)

        axes1.plot((1,2,3), (1,2,3))
        axes2.plot((1,2,3), (1,2,3))
        

        figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

The problem here is that the two graphics displayed are overlayed:

[image: The two graphics are overlayed]

Would there be any way to display them one in top of the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
axes1 = figure.add_subplot(2,1,1)
axes2 = figure.add_subplot(2,1,2)
```